# Why am I getting this kind of error?

Tags: discussion, support

I am trying to answer a question; when I press the "Post Your answer" button, I receive this error, and my account is stuck for some time.

[image]

Comment: Which question are you trying to respond to? What is the exact text of the answer you're trying to submit?

Comment: They felt like showing you a picture of a cat using the computer. Isn't it cute!? Meow!

Comment: not seeing any exceptions in the logs, when did this happen / is it still happening?

Comment: I am just trying to answer one Question and after some time it's comes like this.I was just submit text only nothing other than it.

Comment: No now it's working fine but before few minutes it's shows me something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look through the haproxy logs in the last 48 hours for your IP address and found no errors we reported to you. This is likely to be an issue with the proxy server you are behind, perhaps it is had a copy of the error page cached.

Comment: See I have taken the Screen shot of that time as well